# Copy contents of tmp_path -> tmp_path_factory for use in the next test

Tags: pytest

Test_1 writes out a file tree to the standard tmp_path fixture.

Test_2 requires this file tree as the input to its own test.

I am using `shutil.copytree()` however I am getting an error:

```
import pytest
import shutil
import os

def test_1(tmp_path, tmp_path_factory):
    p = tmp_path / "me"
    shutil.copytree(p, tmp_path_factory, dirs_exist_ok=True)
    assert True

def test_2(tmp_path_factory):
    l = list(tmp_path_factory.iterdir())
    print(l)
    assert False
```

Error:

```
p = TempPathFactory(_given_basetemp=None, _trace=<pluggy._tracing.TagTracerSub object at 0x000002161F3F4BE0>, _basetemp=WindowsPath('C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pytest-of-David/pytest-1125'))

    def split(p):
        """Split a pathname.
    
        Return tuple (head, tail) where tail is everything after the final slash.
        Either part may be empty."""
>       p = os.fspath(p)
E       TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TempPathFactory
```

Any ideas? Many thanks :)

Comment: The error says it pretty clear - `tmp_path_factory` is not a path, it's a factory that creates paths. E.g. `tmp_path_factory.mktemp("fizz")` will create and return a path which you can use for fs operations. If you need to reuse the created path, create a new session-scoped fixture `fs_cache` and use that instead.

Comment: thank you, I was a bit confused about this class, the api docs don't say much

Comment: I agree, the docs are missing the essential bits on the topic. The type hints might help if your IDE offers support for them: `from pytest import TempPathFactory` and `def test(tmp_path_factory: TempPathFactory, ...): ...` will show you available methods in code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hoefling, this works

```
import pytest
import shutil
from directory_tree import display_tree


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def cache_dir(tmp_path_factory):
    return tmp_path_factory.mktemp("cache")#, numbered=False)


def test_1(tmp_path, cache_dir):
    p = tmp_path / "me.txt"
    p.touch()
    shutil.copytree(p.parent, cache_dir, dirs_exist_ok=True)
    assert True


def test_2(cache_dir):
    display_tree(cache_dir)
    assert False
```